# How to get Voximplant call recording URL?

Tags: voximplant

In Voximplant scenario, when a call recording ends, I need to take the URL of the recording and send it via a POST request.

I don't understand how can I do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve call record URL by listening to [CallEvents.RecordStarted](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/voxengine/callevents#recordstarted) event. The URL then can be passed to your web services using [Net.httpRequestAsync](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/voxengine/net/httprequestasync) function

```
let call = callPSTN("18881112233", "14434434434");
call.record();
call.addEventListener(CallEvents.RecordStatred, async (e) => {
  const recordUrl = e.url;
  await Net.httpRequestAsync("https://example.org", {method: "POST", postData: recordUrl});
});
```